# Unable to select the radio button using Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath, selenium, radio-button, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn Selenium WebDriver (Internet Explorer). In this process I have started automating the sprint.com to select a phone and an individual plan. Below are the steps I am following:

1. Open sprint.com
2. Select Just Browsing --> Personal
3. Navigate to Shop --> Phones
4. Enter Zip = 22042 and Start Shopping
5. Click on any phone
6. Click on Add to cart
7. Click on Individual Plan
8. Select Unlimited Plan (Here I'm failing)

Below is the code snippets I tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"pln2860004prd\"]")).click();
```

I'm able to read the attributes by using the same xpath.

```
System.out.println("NAME: " + driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value=\"pln2860004prd\"]")).getAttribute("name"));
```

Please help!

Ranjan

Comment: I want to select the radio button, so I need the code for it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is a nasty browser to test in.

It can be because of several causes. But most likely because the element does not have focus.

So set the **focus** before clicking:

```
if (element instanceof Locatable) {
    Locatable remoteElement = (Locatable) inputElement;          
    remoteElement.getLocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with asgoth... I think driving IE is just fine when you understand how to handle the window handles, etc.

Try this (assuming "driver" is a static member of your test suite):

```
public static void mouseClickByLocator( String cssLocator ) {    
     String locator = cssLocator;    
     WebElement el = driver.findElement( By.cssSelector( locator ) );    
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);    
     builder.moveToElement( el ).click( el );    
     builder.perform();    
}
```

Comment: I haven't used a static driver. But I still tried using the Action class. It did NOT work.

WebElement radioButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='selectMinutes' and @value='" + plan + "']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.moveToElement(radioButton).click(radioButton);
builder.perform();

Will you please try the website and see if you're able to click the radiobutton?

Comment: If you post your code to a github Gist, I can look at it and try it.  I don't have time to write a standalone script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
"//input[@name='selectMinutes' and @value='pln2860004prd']"
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer

Comment: With the above snippet I'm getting the same results. I can get the attributes of the element but can't click it.